# Show only visible items and groups where group has items

Tags: laravel

I have these two queries, but I get half the correct result in each.

I have `group` tables and `item` tables.
You can set `item` records invisible.
You can set `group` records invisible.
You also have some cases where `group` records dont have any related `item` records ( Empty Group ).

I want to select all `group` records which are visible and has related `item` records.

*This returns empty group records ( groups with no related items )*

```
            return  $this->model->with( [ 'items' => function($query){
                        $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
                    }])
                ->where("hos_id",$hos_id)
                ->where('invisible','=',FALSE)
                ->orderBy('description', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

*This one returns only groups with item records, but with `hidden` items aswell*

```
            return $this->model->with('items')
                ->whereHas('items',function ($query){
                    $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
                })
                ->where("hos_id",$hos_id)
                ->where('invisible','=',FALSE)
                ->orderBy('description', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
return $this->model->with(['items' => function ($query){
                $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
            }])
            ->whereHas('items',function ($query){
                $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
            })
            ->where("hos_id",$hos_id)
            ->where('invisible','=',FALSE)
            ->orderBy('description', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Explanation...?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin  whereHas() method check on Model and with() method check on relation and retrieve that particular records from db.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood 100% so I've written the following as simple as possible and you can pick it apart if it doesn't work.

The *left* join should permit groups with no items (empty group)

```
Group::leftJoin('items', function ($join) {
        $join->on('groups.id', '=', 'items.group_id')
             ->where('invisible', false);
    })
    ->where('invisible', false)
    ->get();
```